# Confused with IIS locaton of the virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 and when I go to InetMgr, I right-click on the default website and then choose Explore. I see:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot

So far so good and as expected.

Now I created a C# web application and created a virtual directory under the default website. I right-click and explore I see :

> C:\CSharpTest\WebApplication8\WebApplication8

This is also can be expected. However, when I run the Application, pictures are not loaded since the `WebApplication8` folder is not created in  `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

I know .NET 2.0 VS 2005 does create the folder in inetpub\wwwroot. So under VS 2010 do I need to copy files manually to the Inetpub/wwwroot?

When the page loads I see an empty picture place holder. If I right-click on it and then choose properties I see:

http://aocalhost.com/WebApplication8/pics/a.jpg

Then If I put this directly into the IE:

http://alocalhost.com/WebApplication8/pics/a.jpg

I get an empty page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer after spending 5 hours googling.

I tried almost a dozen of solutions but what worked for me was to enable static contents for the IIS.(Use Add/Remove Software in control panel/windows features)